# Can you formulate an SQL command for this case?

Tags: sqlite

I have an SQLite table PERSONS with the following columns, all integers:

```
PIN (unique ID)
SEX (1 = male, 2 = female)
FATHER_PIN (PIN of person's father)
MOTHER_PIN
```

I want to find all couples that had no children, in other words all PIN 1/ PIN 2 pairs that never appear in FATHER_PIN/MOTHER_PIN.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how we did it. First, create a list of couples:

```
create table COUPLES (HUSB int, WIFE int)
INSERT INTO COUPLES (HUSB,WIFE)  
select 
    EVENTS.PIN, 
    EVENTS.EV_SEQNO
from EVENTS inner join PERSONS on PERSONS.PIN = EVENTS.PIN and PERSONS.SEX =1 and EVENTS.EV_TYPE = 2
where EVENTS.DUAL_KEY = 1
```

Event type '2' is marriage; Sex '1' is Male; EV_SEQNO is PIN of spouse; Dual-key means there is an index on EV_SEQNO.

Next, the query:

```
select 
    HUSB as Husband_PIN,
    (select PERSONS.NAME from PERSONS where PIN = HUSB) as NAME,
    WIFE as Wife_PIN,
    (select PERSONS.NAME from PERSONS where PIN = WIFE) as NAME,
    (HUSB || ',' || WIFE ) as Marriage_PINs
from COUPLES
where Marriage_PINs not in
    (select distinct  (FATHER_PIN || ',' || MOTHER_PIN)
from PERSONS)
```

We are aliasing the Name columns 'NAME' because it triggers special post-processing.

Comment: Note that this will also select those couples where the father or the mother had children with other people, but not inside the couple.  I don't know if this is desiderd or not.

Comment: No, it doesn't, because the husband/wife pair with the other children, appear in the FATHER_PIN/MOTHER_PIN list, and fail the "not in" condition.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the actual couples, because if they have no children there is nothing that relates the two spouses.

You can only get all the possible combinations of a man with no children with a woman with no children.

```
SELECT f.PIN, m.PIN 
FROM persons f JOIN persons m
WHERE f.SEX=1 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM persons WHERE FATHER_PIN=f.PIN)
AND m.SEX=2 AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM persons WHERE MOTHER_PIN=m.PIN)
```

---

If you have a COUPLES table with HUSB and WIFE PINs, then you can instead search that table for couples without children:

```
SELECT HUSB, WIFE
FROM couples
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM persons WHERE FATHER_PIN = couples.HUSB OR MOTHER_PIN = couples.WIFE)
```

Comment: @Charlieface the operation is indeed a CROSS JOIN, but in Sqlite there is no difference between the "CROSS JOIN", "INNER JOIN", "JOIN" and "," join operators. Only exception is that CROSS JOIN is treated differently by the optimizer and as such is not recommended.

Comment: You are correct, I have to create a temporary table. There is also an EVENTS table containing marriages, and PIN of HUSBAND and WIFE. Assume I create a table COUPLES containing the PINs of all the couples. How would I then select all the couples whose HUSB and WIFE PINs never appear in PERSONS.FATHER_PIN and PERSON.MOTHER_PIN? It involves 'count' and selecting from subsets, but I can't figure out how to do this.

Comment: @Pierre I added a query to search the couples table

Answer (score -1):

To find all couples that have no children, you can perform a self-join on the PERSONS table twice (once for mother and once for father) and then filter out the couples who appear in the FATHER_PIN or MOTHER_PIN columns.

Here is a query that identifies all couples that have no children:

```
SELECT 
    m1.PIN AS Mother_PIN, 
    m1.SEX AS Mother_SEX, 
    f1.PIN AS Father_PIN, 
    f1.SEX AS Father_SEX
FROM 
    PERSONS m1
JOIN 
    PERSONS f1 ON m1.PIN = f1.MOTHER_PIN
LEFT JOIN 
    PERSONS m2 ON m1.PIN = m2.MOTHER_PIN
LEFT JOIN 
    PERSONS f2 ON f1.PIN = f2.FATHER_PIN
WHERE 
    m1.SEX = 2 AND f1.SEX = 1 
    AND m2.PIN IS NULL AND f2.PIN IS NULL;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get no records returned. Here is a sample database: http://findyourfamilytree.com/upload/kennedy2.DB